# Need help with Double variable equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve $$x^2+xy+y^2-8=0$$

Comment: You cannot solve 2 variables with one equation.

Comment: Are you restricting $x,y$ to be integers? If so, there are no solutions. If $x,y$ are reals, there are infinitely many.

Comment: You can solve it for $x$ or $y$ since it is a quadratic

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can find solutions $(x,y)$ numerically: HEre is the graph of $x^2+xy+y^2-8=0$. As it is evident from the picture, the solution set is an ellipse:

[image]

Comment: Or just roatate by 45 degree the original equation becomes standard ellipse equation.